# authsource in mongodb spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Hi I am using Spring MVC with MongoDB.
I would like to know where i have to mention the parameter "Authsource=admin".
same time i am not able to give mongoCredentials in mongoTemplate bean, it throwing bean create exception.

Below is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="54.172.243.152" />
    <property name="port" value="27005" />
</bean>
<bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="smynapati" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="smynapati" />
    <!-- <constructor-arg name="authSource" value="admin" /> -->
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <!-- <constructor-arg name="mongoCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials" /> -->
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test1" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" /> 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.userlogin"/>
<bean id="ViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using version `1.5.2.RELEASE` of `spring-data-mongodb` (as I remember from a previous question of yours) and the credentials are stored in the `admin` database these should be your MongoDB related beans settings:

```
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="54.172.243.152" />
    <property name="port" value="27005" />
</bean>
<bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="smynapati" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="smynapati" />
</bean>
```

These stay intact. Next come:

```
<bean id="mongoDbFactory" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test1" />
    <constructor-arg name="credentials" ref="mongoCredentials" />
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationDatabaseName" value="admin" />
</bean>
```

Finally comes the template:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

Note that you'd better use the `mongo` XML namespace for simplicity.

Comment: Orid, still i need your help.
i am facing below exception.

org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [test1], username = [smynapati], password = [s*******i]

Comment: my apologies Orid, it is working. i am trying to look into secondary (slave). that's why faced above issue. Thanks Orid. if i need any help i will open new case please help me out in that. :)